# (Swift) What is the easiest way to delete all elements in array when condition is true

Tags: arrays, swift, remove-if

setsOfCardsByLevel is an array of cards. 
Every card has a level.
 I want to remove all cards from array if their level is equal to level from the parameter.
Here is my function:

```
 func removeCardsByLevel(_ level: Int) {
            for card in setsOfCards {
                if card.level == level {
                    setsOfCards.remove // HOW?
                }
              }
          }
```

Advices? Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to remove the cards that matches a certain level?

```
setsOfCards.removeAll { $0.level == level }
```